# Clear the output area

Tags: javascript, html

I have here a working code that lets the user input something and it displays the output right away, but I want to create a function triggered by a button that would clear the output area itself. Is this possible with my code?

Here is my complete code:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
        <title>Sample Array</title>
        <script>var index = 0;</script>
    </head> 

    <body>


        Input:
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="press(input.value)">

        <p id = "display">

        <script>

            var sample = new Array();

            function press(Number)
            {

                if ( Number != '' )
                {
                    sample[index] = Number;
                    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sample[index] + "<br>";
                    index++;

                }   

                else
                    alert("empty");

                document.getElementById('input').value = '';        
            }       


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output area?

Comment: within the page itself is the output area below the inputbox and button.

Comment: You mean to clear the `<p id = "display">` tag inside content . Am i right?

Comment: yes i want to make a button that could clear the contents of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

Notes:

-I have closed the P element.

-A new button was added "Clean" and you can use JQuery as it is shown below to clean the output (remember to have JQuery referenced in your page).

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Sample Array</title>
    <script>var index = 0;</script>
</head> 

<body>


    Input:
    <input type="text" id="input" />
    <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="press(input.value)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Clean" onClick="$('#display').html('');"/>
    <p id = "display"></p>
    <script>

        var sample = new Array();

        function press(Number)
        {

            if ( Number != '' )
            {
                sample[index] = Number;
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sample[index] + "<br>";
                index++;

            }   

            else
                alert("empty");

            document.getElementById('input').value = '';        
        }       


    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: yes it works. but i want to make it work while not connected to the internet. is there any work around for it?

Comment: replace the onclick code on the Clean button: onClick="document.getElementById('display').innerHTML='';"

Comment: or also you can save the Jquery library in a new JS file and reference it in you page using the script tags <script src="..the path of you js file.." ></script> . Rememeber to put this reference into the HEAD element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**Javascript:**

```
function Clean(){
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML='';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="Clean" onClick="Clean()"/>
```

Comment: @Krish R The answer is ok but there is a typo in your answer!  getElementById -- the 'e' was missing ......